# reveal without reloading page javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

Is it possible to add a paragraph or line of text using a div onClick using javascript, without reloading the page?

```
<a onclick="reveal">Click me!</a>
  <div id="vTitle">
      <!-- show text in this div -->
  </div>

<script type="text/javascript">
  if (onclick == "reveal"){
    var newListItem = document.createElement('p');
    var newListItemText = document.createTextNode('Vualà');
    newListItem.appendChild(newListItemText);
    var newListItemPosition = document.getElementById('vTitle');
    newListItemPosition.appendChild(newListItem);
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use jquery for dom manipulation. Bellow is the jquery code and little modified hmtl.

The jquery

```
$(document).ready(function () {

        $("#reveal").on('click', function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            $("#vTitle").append("<p>Test</p>");
        });
 });
```

And Html is

```
<a id="reveal">Click me!</a>
<div id="vTitle">
    <!-- show text in this div -->
</div>
```

Comment: still nothing appearing

Comment: I have checked it and it is rendering. Did you check the console of the web page? Does your application has jquery library?

Comment: Sorry, my fault. It works now. I had a typo in the jquery-3.2.1.min.js src

Answer (score 0):

You have to first call an function in the `onclik` of `a`. Since its `a` tag, we will have to `preventDefault` so the page does not redirect in case you add a `href` to it.

Click me!

Then in `reveal` function we write a simple code to show a line of text.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 function reveal(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var newListItem = document.createElement('p');
    var newListItemText = document.createTextNode('Vualà');
    newListItem.appendChild(newListItemText);
    var newListItemPosition = document.getElementById('vTitle');
    newListItemPosition.appendChild(newListItem);
 }
</script>
```

If you click multiple times, then multiple `p` tag will be added to the `div`.